# Return enum through a function

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I tried researching this, but could find a solution that fit my situation.

So i'm trying to make a basic wrapper for the metadata of a mysql field:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "mysql.h"


namespace escobar { namespace storage {

    class mysql_field_metadata
    {
    private:
        uint32_t result_index;          /* For indexing the field for a mysql record. */
        std::string name;               /* The name of the column. */
        std::string original_name;      /* The original name of the column, if the name is an alias. */
        std::string table;              /* Name of the table */
        std::string original_table;     /* The original name of the table, if the table name is an alias. */
        std::string database;           /* The name of the database the table/record belongs to. */
        uint32_t length;                /* The length of the field. */
        uint32_t max_length;            /* The maximum length of the set. */
        uint32_t decimals;              /* Number of decimals used in the field. */
        uint32_t charset;               /* Table charset. */
        enum enum_field_types type;     /* The type of MYSQL data. */

    public:
        mysql_field_metadata(MYSQL_FIELD* field_data, uint32_t _result_index) : 
            result_index(_result_index), name(field_data->name),
            original_name(field_data->org_name), table(field_data->table),
            original_table(field_data->org_table), database(field_data->db),
            length(field_data->length), max_length(field_data->max_length),
            decimals(field_data->decimals), charset(field_data->charsetnr),
            type(field_data->type)
        {
        }

        ~mysql_field_metadata(void) { }
        std::string get_name(void) { return this->name; }
        std::string get_original_name(void) { return this->original_name; }
        std::string get_table(void) { return this->original_name; }
        std::string get_original_table(void) { return this->original_table; }
        std::string get_database(void) { return this->database; }
        uint32_t get_length(void) { return this->length; }
        uint32_t get_max_length(void) { return this->max_length; }
        uint32_t get_decimals(void) { return this->decimals; }
        uint32_t get_charset(void) { return this->charset; }
        enum emum_field_types get_type(void) { return this->type; }
    };

}}
```

As you can see, my last function:

`enum emum_field_types get_type(void) { return this->type; }`

It doesn't seem to be working, I get the following error:

`error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'enum_field_types' to 'escobar::storage::emum_field_types'
1>          Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)`

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact error message.

Comment: I edited the question with the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **don't** need to prefix it with `enum`. You can try to remove it both from the function and the member and report back. It is possibly confusing the compiler.

```
enum_field_types type;     /* The type of MYSQL data. */
...
emum_field_types get_type(void) {
```

Edit: To fix your "indentifier is undeclared" issue, use `namespace::typename` syntax if it in a namespace or `::typename` if no namespace

Comment: Hey, I tried this and it still doesn't work. The original enum_field_types is declared in a file called "mysql_com.h" which is included by "mysql.h". When I remove the "enum" keyword, it says the indentifier is undeclared

Comment: @TheAJ is it in a `namespace`? try `namespace::typename` syntax or `::typename` if no namespace

Comment: @TheAJ guess so, glad I could help!

Comment: Using elaborated typenames, while almost never necessary in C++, shouldn't be a problem. Since you currently guessed the problem, you should edit that into your answer to make it the main point.

Comment: @Code-Guru: I don't see where such a claim is made.

Comment: @GManNickG Parse error: missed the "don't" in the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

From the compiler error, it seems that there are two different declarations for `enum_field_types`. Probably one is inside your namespace and one is global. You have two possible solutions:

1. If both declarations are in your own code, you can track down both of these declarations and remove one of them.
2. You can qualify which declaration to use with the `namespace::typename` syntax.

Choice 1. should be preferred because using the same name for two different declarations, especially when one of those declarations is in the global namespace, can cause some subtle bugs and compiler errors.